# Wordpress custom MU plugin fetch user details

Tags: wordpress

I hope you can help
I have a wordpress multisite with a custom login which takes users to the root wp-admin by default which gives this error for those who do not have the correct permission.

```
You attempted to access the "WordPress" dashboard, but you do not currently have privileges on this site. If you believe you should be able to access the "WordPress" dashboard, please contact your network administrator.
```

I would like them to be redirected to the primary blog like this example.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatic-redirection-to-child-site-from-main?replies=15

However, my custom plugin in my mu-plugins does not contain $current_user and none of the functions to get the current user work.
The other functions I have built work no problem, so I know there is nothing wrong with the file getting included.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end.
I hope this helps someone

```
function check_if_user_needs_redirecting(){
    $active_blog = get_active_blog_for_user(get_current_user_id());
    $blogid = get_current_blog_id();
    if ($blogid != $active_blog->blog_id){
        header('Location: '.$active_blog->siteurl.'/wp-admin/');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'check_if_user_needs_redirecting' );
```

Comment: Seems like a very bad solution running this at *every WP page* (front and back end, and even Ajax). If you post details of your custom login in the Question, maybe there's a better solution.